# Datatables Ajax Source

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables and loading data via ajax.  The table will never have alot of rows so pagination, searching and sorting is not needed.  The below code works perfect except the pagination controls and information (Showing 1 to 2 of 2 entries)  is still visible.  I have tried to add "bPaginate": false to the initialization of the table but then it never displays the data.  It just says "processing"...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {



    var dataTable = $('#dataTablecontacts').dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/Contact/GetDataTable/@Model.Id",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bSort": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "aaSorting": [[1, "asc"]],
        "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "Id", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, bVisible: false },
                    { "mData": "Name" },
                    { "mData": "Position" },
                    { "mData": "OfficePhone", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
                    { "mData": "MobilePhone", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
                    { "mData": "Email", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false },
                    { "mData": "BusinessPartner", "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, bVisible: false },
        ]
    });


    $("#dataTablecontacts tbody").on("click", "tr", function (event) {
        var id = dataTable.fnGetData(this)['Id'];
        var viewUrl = "/Contact/Details/" + id;
        window.location = viewUrl;
    });



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this if you just want to hide them:

```
$('.dataTables_paginate, .dataTables_filter').css({display: 'none'});
```

Comment: This does work so i am going to mark it as the answer but i am curious why the bPaginate: false cause the issues i am seeing